Implementation of SSE(Server Sent Events) using HttpServletRequest.newPushBuilder() Always Returning null
I am new to SSE - server sent events implementation.
I am trying to implement SSE using java jakarta.HttpServletRequest.
import java.io.IOException;
import jakarta.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import jakarta.servlet.http.PushBuilder;


@WebServlet("/check-push")
public class PushServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
        final String titleText;
        PushBuilder builder = req.newPushBuilder();
        System.out.println(builder);
    }

}

req.newPushBuilder() always returning null.
I tried to change the configuration of HTTP to 2
using self signed certificate and the required configuration in server.xml
But it does not works.
If anything I missing to implement please guide me.
Thanks in advance for your help.
What is the necessary steps I need to take implementing this with tomcat 10.1
Do I need really a tls certificate to implement SSE or I can implement it in Http 1 as well.

What exactly do you want? Do you want SSE or HTTP/2? These are two completely different things which do not at all depend on each other. The code snippet in your question is for HTTP/2 and completely unrelated to SSE. Take a step back and carefully read yourself into the SSE and HTTP/2 concepts. If you in the end indeed need SSE instead of HTTP/2, then just use JAX-RS as instructed in its documentation.

I am trying to implement a notification system with SSE So I am trying to execute it with SSE,
So I am asking how to implement it in Servlet.
I found that PushBuilder is used to send Server Push.
To get a push Builder I am using the  req.newPushBuilder();
But It always returning  a null instead of PushBuilder.
So I am asking what are the necessary things I need to do implement Server Push

Could Anyone explain what is the purpose of PushBuilder in Servlets

PushBuilder builder = req.newPushBuilder();

This has completely nothing to do with SSE.
This is for HTTP/2 Server Push (RFC 7540) which is a completely different thing than Server-Sent Events (HTML Living Standard).
Basically, HTTP/2 push allows you to send page resources (basically, URLs of CSS/JS/image files referenced by requested HTML page) via response headers so that the client can optionally prefetch them without the need to parse the whole HTML page in order to find them.
In order to use SSE on a servletcontainer, use the JAX-RS API instead. It's not provided by the Servlet API. As Tomcat is not a Jakarta EE compatible container, but a barebones JSP/Servlet/EL/WebSocket container, you've 2 options:

Manually install JAX-RS (basicaslly, just put its JARs in /WEB-INF/lib)
Or, switch to a Jakarta EE compatible server such as TomEE or WildFly or GlassFish.

In case you wish to manually install JAX-RS, you'll first need to pick a JAX-RS implementation and read its documentation. Here are the currently available JAX-RS implementations, pick one of them.

Eclipse Jersey
JBoss RESTEasy
Apache CXF

After having installed JAX-RS or having switched to a normal Jakarta EE server (without the need to manually install JAX-RS (and the rest of Jakarta EE)), then you can start implementing SSE as per section 9.3. 'Server API' of chapter 9. 'Server-Sent Events' of the JAX-RS documentation.

Thanks for the clear explanation
Now I have got a clear Idea about everything and get the desired output
